# Improving the availability and minimising the cost of website API on AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

Suppose I own a simple API for my website that receives about 1,000 requests each day and has
an average response time of 50 ms. It is currently hosted on one c4.large instance. To provide high availability at the lowest cost, is it better to create an Auto Scaling Group and use an Application Load Balancer to balance the traffic or recreate the API using Amazon API Gateway and use AWS Lambda as the service backend?

Comment: Your question is generic . Sadly you haven't provided any relevant info about your application. Not every application is suited or even possible to be replaced using lambdas and api gateway.

Comment: maybe look into Serverless: AWS Lambda + API Gateway?

Answer (score 1):

Generally EC2 is less flexible in matching resource consumption to cost when compared to Lambda.
Though there are a whole set of problems when you want to get into Lambda from EC2 world

- Is your application type supported on Lambda? If yes, what is the cost of adapting to Lambda's architecture? Even for something considered "simple web API" in EC2 world can lead to huge refactor in Lambda such as when your application expected payload is big or the codebase is using local disk drive extensively
- Can you accept the frequent cold-start slow response from lambda. I have seen really simple .NET Core application takes 400-500ms on cold start alone... etc.
- I suggest if you have not deployed and used an application on Lambda, do not just blindly try to move them to Lambda from EC2. Start with really small projects and understand the most common pitfalls or [read some articles first](https://medium.com/@emaildelivery/serverless-pitfalls-issues-you-may-encounter-running-a-start-up-on-aws-lambda-f242b404f41c)